# QEMU KVM hangs "Booting from Hard Disk... "

Tags: hard-drive, kvm-virtualization, qemu, hanging

- Ubuntu 20.04 server (no GUI) as host
- several guests working perfectly, each with its own LV
- I created an LV for a VM called "test", similar to working guests
- Partitioned the LV:  one ext4 bootable partition, one swap
- root system rsync-d onto the bootable partition.
- created a new VM using virt-install thus:

  virt-install --name=test                    
  --memory 2000                       
  --vcpus 2                           
  --disk path=/dev/vg-main/test,bus=virtio,cache=none,format=raw 
  --network="bridge=br0,model=virtio" 
  --graphics vnc,port=5905            
  --noautoconsole                     
  --import                            
  --os-type=generic

When I start the VM, it hangs as follows:

```
SeaBIOS (version 1.13.0-1ubuntu1.1)
Machine UUID <uuid of xml file>
iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP+7CF8C880+7CECC880 CA00

Booting from Hard Disk...
```

The file system is mountable and complete:

```
root@virtual3:~/test# losetup /dev/loop7 /dev/vg-main/test
root@virtual3:~/test# kpartx -av /dev/loop7
add map loop7p1 (253:11): 0 95614977 linear 7:7 3999744
add map loop7p2 (253:12): 0 5238784 linear 7:7 99616768
root@virtual3:~/test# mount /dev/mapper/loop7p1 /mnt
root@virtual3:~/test# ls /mnt
backup  build  etc   initrd          lib         mnt   root  srv  usr      vmlinuz.old
bin     cdrom  from  initrd.img      lost+found  opt   run   sys  var
boot    dev    home  initrd.img.old  media       proc  sbin  tmp  vmlinuz
```

and the output of fdisk /dev/vg-main/test looks like this:

```
Disk /dev/vg-main/test: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 02EA0DD2-3166-495C-9E0F-37DDEFD15786

Device                Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/vg-main/test1  3999744  99614720 95614977 45.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/vg-main/test2 99616768 104855551  5238784  2.5G Linux swap
```

I've compared the .xml file with other working .xml files and I can't see anything obvious.

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
  <source dev='/dev/vg-main/test'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

I can't see any error message in the logs. I think I must have missed an important step.. .any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are booting a GPT disk with the default old-style BIOS, which will not work. Try appending `--machine q35 --boot uefi` to `virt-install`

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue - i.e. stuck on the screen

but I build it with the following

iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP+7CF8C880+7CECC880 CA00

Booting from Hard Disk...

sudo virt-builder ubuntu-20.04 --update --install build-essential --root-password file:pwdfile 
--firstboot-command 'useradd -m -p "" rjones ; chage -d 0 rjones' 
-o ./ub.img